# How to compare dates from just only one table, SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, compare, sql-server-2016

I need help because im doing a project and i need to compare dates in SQL server, i need to get the names of the persons that recieved visitations on the same date and i cant do it.

```
create table Visit (

    Id_Visit int not null identity primary key,
    NumberVisits int not null,
    DescriptionVisits varchar(500) not null,
    DateVisit date not null,
    TimeVisit time not null,
    Person int not null,
    foreign key(Person) references Person(NumPerson)
);

insert into Visit values(2, 'Visita pela filha Joana e pelo neto João', '05-18-2020', '15:30', 1);

insert into Visit values(1, 'Visita pelo amigo Artur', '08-10-2020', '10:00', 2);

insert into Visit values(1, 'Visita pelo filho Joaquim', '09-14-2020', '17:10', 3);

insert into Visit values(1, 'Visita pelo advogado Firminio', '08-11-2020', '15:50', 2);

insert into Visit values(3, 'Visita pelas amigas Belandina, Carmélia e Rosa', '08-10-2020', '14:30', 1);


--Change Date from visit 3

update Visit 
set DateVisit = cast('2020-05-18' as date)
where Id_Visit = 3

--Change Time from visit 3

update Visit
set TimeVisit = cast('15:30' as time)
where Id_Visit = 3

--Change Date from visit 2

update Visit
set DateVisit = cast('2020-05-18' as date)
where Id_Visit = 2;
```

I want to do a select that only show de number of the persons that had visits in the same date.

Comment: Please add the desired result to your question (use [Edit]).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/896ff/2/0

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person
FROM Visit
WHERE DateVisit IN (
  SELECT DateVisit
  FROM Visit
  GROUP By DateVisit
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

This finds the dates that exist more than once in the `Visit` table (ie. there are multiple visits on that day), then pulls the `Person`s that were visited.

Comment: @kevo3234 If you found the answer helpful, be sure to ACCEPT it.   It small gesture of thanks for Aaron's time and talent and indicates to other contributors the issue has been closed

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this code

```
SELECT DateVisit ,COUNT(DISTINCT Person) AS PersonCount
FROM Visit GROUP BY DateVisit
```

You can also use the condition

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Person) AS PersonCount
FROM Visit WHERE datevisit = '2020-05-18'
```